# How to reshape DataFrame to get 3-D array using a sliding window?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to reshape my DataFrame `df`:

```
flights = {
            'flight_stage':   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
            'scheduled_hour': [16,16,17,17,17,18,18],
            'delay_category': [1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2]
        }

columns = ['flight_stage', 'scheduled_hour', 'delay_category']

df = pd.DataFrame(flights, columns=columns)
```

I want to get the following 3-D array `X`:

```
[
  [[1,16],[0,16],[1,17]],
  [[0,16],[1,17],[1,17]],
  [[1,17],[1,17],[0,17]],
  [[1,17],[0,17],[0,18]],
  [[0,17],[0,18],[1,18]]
]
```

and 1-D array `y`:

```
[
  3,
  4,
  5,
  3,
  3
]
```

Basically, the original DataFrame `df` should be reshaped using a sliding window of 1, taking last 3 entries, in order to get `X`. The values of `y` should be a sum of `delay_category` of all 3 entries.

How can I do it?

I tried to use `reshape`, but didn't come up with any solution.

Comment: Could you care to expand on the logic behind X?

Comment: @DanielMesejo: Yes, sure. I take 3 first rows of `df` (columns `flight_stage` and  `scheduled_hour`). Then I slide 1 row and take another 3 rows. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pprint
import pandas as pd

flights = {
            'flight_stage':   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
            'scheduled_hour': [16,16,17,17,17,18,18],
            'delay_category': [1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2]
        }

columns = ['flight_stage', 'scheduled_hour', 'delay_category']

df = pd.DataFrame(flights, columns=columns)
X = [df.iloc[i:i+3, [0, 1]].values.tolist() for i in range(len(df) - (3 - 1))]
y = df.delay_category.rolling(3).sum().dropna()

pprint.pprint(X)
pprint.pprint(y)
```

**Output**

```
[[[1, 16], [0, 16], [1, 17]],
 [[0, 16], [1, 17], [1, 17]],
 [[1, 17], [1, 17], [0, 17]],
 [[1, 17], [0, 17], [0, 18]],
 [[0, 17], [0, 18], [1, 18]]]
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    3.0
6    3.0
Name: delay_category, dtype: float64
```

If desired you can convert `X` to a numpy array very easily.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to just loop through your array and stack subarrays of your window size. To get your value `y`, `rolling` method works well here. Something like this should work:

```
arr = df[['flight_stage', 'scheduled_hour']].values

win_size = 3
X = np.stack([arr[n:n+win_size, :] for n in range(len(arr) - win_size + 1)])

y = df['delay_category'].rolling(3, ).sum()
```

Comment: X array contains the same values in all sub-arrays.

Comment: There is no `[0,17],[0,18],[1,18]` (should be last line).

Comment: @ScalaBoy Just need to increase the range by 1. Updated the list comprehension to include the last window.

Answer (score 1):

For a better performance, you can use `numpy` and stack together slices of the array:

```
w = 3
cols = 2
rows = x.shape[0] - window + 1
x = df.values
X = np.hstack((x[:-2,:2], x[1:-1,:2], x[2:,:2])).reshape((rows,w,cols))

print(X)
array([[[ 1, 16],
        [ 0, 16],
        [ 1, 17]],

       [[ 0, 16],
        [ 1, 17],
        [ 1, 17]],

       [[ 1, 17],
        [ 1, 17],
        [ 0, 17]],

       [[ 1, 17],
        [ 0, 17],
        [ 0, 18]],

       [[ 0, 17],
        [ 0, 18],
        [ 1, 18]]], dtype=int64)

print(y)
y = np.vstack((x[:-2,-1], x[1:-1,-1], x[2:,-1])).sum(axis=0)

    array([3, 4, 5, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

---

Some time comparissons:

```
def daniel(df):
    columns = ['flight_stage', 'scheduled_hour', 'delay_category']
    X = [df.iloc[i:i+3, [0, 1]].values.tolist() for i in range(len(df) - (3 - 1))]
    y = df.delay_category.rolling(3).sum().dropna()

def busybear(df):
    arr = df[['flight_stage', 'scheduled_hour']].values
    win_size = 3
    X = np.stack([arr[n:n+win_size, :] for n in range(len(arr) - win_size + 1)])
    y = df['delay_category'].rolling(3, ).sum()

def yatu(df):
    x = df.values
    w = 3
    cols = 2
    rows = x.shape[0] - window + 1
    X = np.hstack((x[:-2,:2], x[1:-1,:2], x[2:,:2])).reshape((rows,w,cols))
    y = np.vstack((x[:-2,-1], x[1:-1,-1], x[2:,-1])).sum(axis=0)

%timeit daniel(df)
# 2.75 ms ± 389 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit yatu(df)
# 26.3 µs ± 2.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit busybear(df)
# 929 µs ± 179 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: The structure of X is different in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @ScalaBoy, needed a reshape